# R Programming- sort a list by number of words

Tags: r, sorting, vector

I have a list with several responses to a survey. I am trying to sort the elements in the list by the number of words in each response. Everything I have found online uses nchar, which sorts by number of characters instead of words.

This is what I have so far:

```
gala.vector <- unlist(strsplit, gala.list, " ")
```

### split the vector by spaces to split it up between words

```
gala.list.sorted <- gala.list[order(gala.vector, decreasing=TRUE)]
```

However I am being told that the argument "gala.vector is not a vector and receiving an error message

Answer (score 0):

We can `split` the sentence in each of the `list` elements ('gala.list'), `unlist` it ('lst1'), use `lengths` to get the 'length' of each of the `list` elements and `order` on it to order the 'gala.list'

```
lst1 <- lapply(gala.list, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, " ")))
gala.list[order(lengths(lst1), decreasing = TRUE)]
```

#### data

```
gala.list <- list("something else to do", "three words only",    
              "using dput")
```

Answer (score 0):

Reproducible example and function solution:

```
w <- c("this has four words", 
  "this one has five words", 
  "two words")

word_count <- function(x) {
  x <- lapply(x, function(y) trimws(strsplit(y, " ")[[1]]))
  x <- lapply(x, function(y) y[y != ""])
  unlist(lapply(x, length))
}

> word_count(w)
# [1] 4 5 2 

sort_by_wc <- function(x, decreasing = TRUE) {
  seq <- word_count(x)
  x[order(seq, decreasing = decreasing)]
}

> sort_by_wc(w)
# [1] "this one has five words" 
# [2] "this has four words"    
# [3] "two words"
```